Wordpress home url wrong only in 1 place
I used all-in-one WP migration tool to backup and move my site to another domain. After that I changed the home and siteurl from settings. Everything works fine, except the logo in my homepage header still points to old url. All other links point to new domain.
I don't get what's the problem. I tried to grep the www root to find any references to old domain, no matches. I used wp-cli to check siteurl and home from database wp_options table and they are correct. I loaded the page in incognito with cache disabled. It has been a few weeks, so I think any caches should be cleaned anyways.
Any ideas?
[UPDATE]
I found out that the old domain is ghosting around in some db option_values related to "quadmenu" plugin. I removed it, and reinstalled. DB stays the same, so no luck.
Then I followed the code path:
<?php

// logo.php
<a class="quadmenu-navbar-brand img" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link );?>">...</a>

// inherit.php
quadmenu_get_template(
    'logo.php',
    array(
        'url'  => isset( $args->navbar_logo['url'] ) ? $args->navbar_logo['url'] : false,
        'link' => $args->navbar_logo_link,
    )
);
        
// class-configuration.php
$defaults['navbar_logo_link'] = quadmenu_get_translated_home_url( '/');


// class-functions.php
function quadmenu_get_translated_home_url( $param ) {
    $home_url = home_url();
    if ( function_exists( 'pll_home_url' ) ) {
        $home_url = pll_home_url( $param );
    }
    if ( function_exists( 'wpml_get_home_url' ) ) {
        $home_url = wpml_get_home_url( $param );
    }
    return $home_url;
}
?>

So looks like it's just calling home_url() which I think is built into WP?
If i echo home_url() in the same file to the page, it outputs the correct url. I'm lost. pll_home_url and wpml_get_home_url are undefined.

What's the code for your logo header in the theme you are using?

Start by checking the code of that header template, and figure out how the URL it links to there is created.

Where can i find the code for the logo header in my theme? its a custom one

Okay i found out that it uses "quadmenu" plugin for the header, but in it's settings you just make references to pages, no input for urls

you should use wp-cli to check in all tables since the plugin could install its own tables or use others than the ones you already checked

you're right, i found references to old urls in wp_options custom rows. I'll try to recreate the menus and answer this in case somebody else is wondering the same

I updated the Q, this is turning into a wild goose chase

Answering this in case someone has the specific problem of Quadmenu + wrong logo url:
Turns out Quadmenu has it's own setting for logo url, separate from WP. It seems to update when importing a site, but not when you change the site url after importing.
I found this setting at quadmenu->options->default theme->menu and changed it.
